# forward fill specific columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe with multiple columns `['x', 'y', 'z']`, how do I forward fill only one column `'x'`? Or a group of columns `['x','y']`?

I only know how to do it by axis.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

tl;dr:

```
cols = ['X', 'Y']
df.loc[:,cols] = df.loc[:,cols].ffill()
```

And I have also added a self containing example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> ## create dataframe
... ts1 = [0, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
>>> ts2 = [0, 2, np.nan, 3, np.nan, np.nan]
>>> d =  {'X': ts1, 'Y': ts2, 'Z': ts2}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> print(df.head())
    X   Y   Z
0   0   0   0
1   1   2   2
2 NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN   3   3
4 NaN NaN NaN
>>> 
>>> ## apply forward fill
... cols = ['X', 'Y']
>>> df.loc[:,cols] = df.loc[:,cols].ffill()
>>> print(df.head())
   X  Y   Z
0  0  0   0
1  1  2   2
2  1  2 NaN
3  1  3   3
4  1  3 NaN
```

Comment: This throws up a `SettingWithCopyWarning`. Any thoughts on worrying about that warning?

Comment: See the description in here about the preferred way of indexing in Python: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html Changing to .loc statements should solve the issue, I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: If I hope to exclude columns X and Y when I fillna?

Comment: ```## apply forward fill with exclusion
cols_ex = ['X', 'Y'] # define columns to exclude \\
cols = df.columns # get list with all columns \\ 
cols_to_ff = cols.drop(cols_ex) # drop columns to exclude \\
df.loc[:,cols_to_ff] = df.loc[:,cols_to_ff].ffill() # forward fill the selected columns \\
```

Comment: What if the column you want to forward fill is the index?

Answer (score 19):

```
for col in ['X', 'Y']:
    df[col] = df[col].ffill()
```

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively with the `inplace` parameter:

```
df['X'].ffill(inplace=True)
df['Y'].ffill(inplace=True)
```

And no, you cannot do `df[['X','Y]].ffill(inplace=True)` as this first creates a slice through the column selection and hence inplace forward fill would create a SettingWithCopyWarning. Of course if you have a list of columns you can do this in a loop:

```
for col in ['X', 'Y']:
    df[col].ffill(inplace=True)
```

The point of using `inplace` is that it avoids copying the column.

Answer (score 5):

Two columns can be `ffill()` simultaneously as given below:

```
df1 = df[['X','Y']].ffill()
```

Comment: I tried this solution first as it seems cleaner to me but one problem with this solution is that only columns X and Y are saved in the df1 dataframe. The remaining column(s) are not. Both Woody Pride's and Abhishek Chaurasia responses both retain all columns.

Answer (score 4):

I used below code, Here for X and Y method can be different also instead of **ffill()**.

```
 df1 = df.fillna({
        'X' : df['X'].ffill(),
        'Y' : df['Y'].ffill(),
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest version I think.

```
cols = ['X', 'Y']
df[cols] = df[cols].ffill()
```