# Pandas: Change a value in dataframe basing on a other value

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe like this one:

```
A
0
1
2
3
Nan
6
Nan
7
```

I wanna replace all nan values with the latest value before it

```
A
0
1
2
3
3
6
6
7
```

i try to work with conditions but it doesn't work

Comment: check `series.ffill()`

Comment: can you explain it to me please because it doesn't consider the condition?

Comment: check the link in the dupe , and this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27018394/9840637 , the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) and [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) say : `method : {‘backfill’, ‘bfill’, ‘pad’, ‘ffill’, None}, default None
Method to use for filling holes in reindexed Series pad / ffill: propagate last valid observation forward to next valid backfill / bfill: use next valid observation to fill gap.`