# Forward fill certain columns with specified frequency for time series data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series, fill

I want to forward fill 2 columns: `Time` and `X` in `df`:

```
   Time                     X   Y   Z
0  2020-01-15 06:12:49.213  0   0   0
1  2020-01-15 08:12:49.213  1   2   2
2  2020-01-15 10:12:49.213  3   6   9
3  2020-01-15 12:12:49.213  12  15  4
4  2020-01-15 14:12:49.213  8   4   3
```

but keeping remaining columns `Y` and `Z` constant, or fill the additional rows with `NaN`.

I checked Pandas docs for [.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.fillna.html) and [.asfreq](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) but they didn't cover forward fill certain columns. While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27018394/11901732) did, it didn't specify frequency.

Expected output(using `10s` frequency):

```
    Time                     X   Y   Z
0   2020-01-15 06:12:49.213  0   0   0
1   2020-01-15 06:12:59.213  0   NaN NaN  # forward filled 
2   2020-01-15 06:13:09.213  0   NaN NaN  # forward filled 
               ...
11  2020-01-15 08:12:49.213  1   2   2
12  2020-01-15 08:12:59.213  1   NaN NaN  # forward filled 
13  2020-01-15 08:13:09.213  1   NaN NaN  # forward filled 
               ...
22  2020-01-15 10:12:49.213  3   6   9
23  2020-01-15 10:12:59.213  3   NaN NaN  # forward filled 

               ...
```

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: @AlexandreB. Please see edited question.

Comment: So you have a unique time stamp for each value of `X` and you want to create new timestamps `10 seconds` apart?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes, and forward fill `X` column, but keeping `Y` and `Z` intact(fill added rows with `NaN`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) to resample times.

**Workflow:**

- First we set the `Time` column as index
- Sort the index (if there are not, the `asfreq` method will failed)
- Let's now **extend** the dataframe. We operate the resample two times according the method used:

  - If no method is provided (e.g. `None`), new values are filled with `NaN`. We use this for columns `Y` and `Z`
  - For the `X` column, the method `ffill` "propagates last valid observation forward to next valid" [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html).
  - As you highlight in comments, the frequency used is important to know if all the values will be kept. If the frequency is too big, some values might not match the interval. As a result, these values will be skipped. To overcome this, a solution might be to use smaller interval (let's say `1s`). Using it, the `ffill` will be correctly applied to all values.
  - However, if you actually want a `10S` daterange dataframe, we need to resample. Here, we start to understand, by doing that, we will again delete values not in daterange. But it's not problematic because we already have these values (they are our input). So we can append them to our dataframe using [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) (like this, we will be sure to have all the values). We might even have duplicates, so remove them using [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

**Full example:**

```
# Be sure it's a datetime object
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"])
print(df)

# Set tme column as index
df.set_index(["Time"], inplace=True)
df = df.sort_index()
print(df)
#                      Time   X   Y  Z
# 0 2020-01-15 06:12:49.213   0   0  0
# 1 2020-01-15 08:12:49.213   1   2  2
# 2 2020-01-15 10:12:49.213   3   6  9
# 3 2020-01-15 11:45:24.213   4   6  9
# 4 2020-01-15 12:12:49.213  12  15  4
# 5 2020-01-15 12:12:22.213  12  15  4
# 6 2020-01-15 14:12:49.213   8   4  3

# Resample
out = df[["Y", "Z"]].asfreq('10S')
out["X"] = df["X"].asfreq('1S', method="ffill").asfreq('10S')

# Reset index
out = out.append(df, sort=True).reset_index().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
print(out)
#                         Time   X     Y    Z
# 0    2020-01-15 06:12:49.213   0   0.0  0.0
# 1    2020-01-15 06:12:59.213   0   NaN  NaN
# 2    2020-01-15 06:13:09.213   0   NaN  NaN
# 3    2020-01-15 06:13:19.213   0   NaN  NaN
# 4    2020-01-15 06:13:29.213   0   NaN  NaN
# ...                      ...  ..   ...  ...
# 2878 2020-01-15 14:12:29.213  12   NaN  NaN
# 2879 2020-01-15 14:12:39.213  12   NaN  NaN
# 2880 2020-01-15 14:12:49.213   8   4.0  3.0
# 2881 2020-01-15 11:45:24.213   4   6.0  9.0
# 2882 2020-01-15 12:12:22.213  12  15.0  4.0

# [2883 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: I think so. You can keep the index in another column. However, since `asfreq` is expending the dataframe, the index are changed

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have a question: can I still set constraint on time to apply further operations? For example, can I calculate the mean of `data` for `time` between `0am` and `4am`?

Comment: Yes it is. That depends on what you want to do. If you're only looking for a specific daterange, you can subset the dataset and apply [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html). However, if you're looking for a summary for all *4h* daterange, you should have a look at [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html)

Comment: Btw, it seems to have removed the original data, which are not at `10second` intervals - is it possible to keep these original data?