# How to write values from one csv to another on condition using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, conditional-formatting

I have 2 CSV files, in combined_csv I have duplicates of rows (on purpose). I'm trying to merge 2 CSV's such that values from another file (ims_data_new) will be written in relevant cells and columns of the first file.
Code below doesn't do it, it skips "ActivePositive" column.

What I want:
file1:

```
c1   c2
1     a
2     b
3     c
4     d
5     e
```

file2:

```
c3   c4   c5
1    aa   ww
3    bb   rr
5    cc   tt
```

And the expected result:

```
c1   c2    c4   c5
1     a    aa   ww
2     b    aa   ww
3     c    bb   rr
4     d    bb   rr
5     e    cc   tt
```

My code so far:

```
data = pd.read_csv('.../combined_csv.csv', date_parser='datetime')
ims = pd.read_csv('.../ims_data_new.csv', date_parser='datetime')

# merging the files 
f3 = data[["Timestamp",  
         "ActivePositive"]].merge(ims[["Timestamp",  
                                         "Temperature", "Humidity",  
                                         "Wind Speed"]],  
                                     on = "Timestamp",  
                                     how = "right") 
  
# creating a new file 
f3.to_excel("../Results.xlsx", index = False)
```

I'm new to csv and really struggle with writing to csv with conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing the fill forward

```
cols = ['c4', 'c5']
df.loc[:,cols] = df.loc[:,cols].ffill()
```

Have a look at

[forward fill specific columns in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012151/forward-fill-specific-columns-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out b literally doing small steps, here's what I did:
So I formated the data in both csv's:

```
data_file = open(path_data, newline='')
reader = csv.reader(data_file)
header = next(reader)
data1 = []
for row in reader:
    #print(row[0])
    date = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
    active_pos = float(row[1])
    data1.append([date,active_pos])
    
ims_file = open(path_ims, newline='')
reader2 = csv.reader(ims_file)
header2 = next(reader2)
data2 = []
for row in reader2:
    #print(row[0])
    date = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
    temperature = float(row[1])
    humidity = int(row[2])
    windspeed = float(row[3])
    data2.append([date,temperature,humidity,windspeed])
```

Then I just run row by row and saved relevant values:

```
res = []
for i in range(len(data2)):
    for j in range(len(data1)):
        if data1[j][0]==data2[i][0]:
            date = data1[j][0]
            active_pos = data1[j][1]
            temperature = data2[i][1]
            humidity = data2[i][2]
            windspeed = data2[i][3]
            res.append([date,active_pos,temperature,humidity,windspeed])
```

The only issue is that I have HUGE files.
If somebody has a better, more optimal way to do this I will appreciate it a lot!